# Find out the odd numbers from a given number

Tags: javascript

i was trying to solve a codewars kata where it is required to find the count of all the sequential odd-numbered substrings from a given string. Eg: for "1341", the output would be 7 (1, 3, 1, 13, 1341, 341, 41 - repetitions are allowed). The code I wrote below (agreeably not the most efficient) works well for a few test cases, however fails for the bigger numbers. Eg: it works well for '134721', however fails for '555564398422914589479591281194'. I'm a complete beginner, so any help be appreciated.

PS: test case numbers don't have '0', so haven't accounted for that yet.

```
function solve(s) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= s.length; j++) {
      let required = s.slice(i, j);
      
      if (required !== '' && required % 2 === 1) {
        result.push(required);
        }
    }
  }
  return result.length;
}

solve(555564398422914589479591281194) //should return 280, my code is returning 210.
```

Comment: Update: I did eventually use a diff. logic, but just curious as to why this isn't working

Comment: Still struggling to understand what you mean by 'sequential odd-numbered substrings...Eg: for "1341", the output would be 7'. Why is output `7` here?

Comment: 'sequential odd-numbered substrings' by this it means that the numbers should be in order (left to right) and not in an arbitrary permutation and combination. Consequently every individual integer is a sequential substring in itself. Hope I was able to clarify, this is the codewars link (https://www.codewars.com/kata/59da47fa27ee00a8b90000b4/train/ruby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER it's 9007199254740991 so the arithmetic it is not operating correctly.

Instead of verifying the whole number if it is odd, verify the last digit

```
function solve(s) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= s.length; j++) {
      let required = s.slice(i, j);
      if (required !== '' && required[required.length - 1] % 2 === 1) {
        result.push(required);
        }
    }
  }
  return result.length;
}
solve("555564398422914589479591281194")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, in the end I used this itself, but was curious about the behaviour of the code that I wrote. Since it was failing on larger digits, I figured that might be the case.